# vim8: redirect stdout in job

Tags: vim, jobs, io-redirection

why does this not work:

```
:call job_start('echo hello > /tmp/file.txt')
```

I would expect that this creates a file called `file.txt` in `/tmp` with the content `hello`.

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that happens is because the command is executed directly and not through a shell.

To have your intended behaviour, use the way the help pages (`:help job_start`) tell us to:

```
:call job_start(["/bin/sh", "-c", "echo hello > /tmp/file.txt"])
```

Comment: explanation, solution, link-to-help and making-me-feel-stupid in one short answer. Thanks!